# Combining lists and lists in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each value is a list of variables (all variables are floats):

`d = {1:[a,b,c], 2:[d,e,f], 3:[g,h,i]}`

and a list with the same number of elements as there are elements in the combined lists of the dictionary:

`L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I want to combine the list into the dictionary, such that:

`d = {1:[a+1,b+2,c+3], 2:[d+4,e+5,f+6], 3:[g+7,h+8,i+9]}`

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Are you expecting the elements to be strings (e.g. `["a + 1", "b + 2", "c + 3"]`, etc.)?

Comment: @JackMoody nope, both the alphabets and numbers represent floats!

Comment: so are `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. all variables that are assigned float values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

As your question was unclear about what `a`, `b` and so on were supposed to be when you first asked your question, I used strings for simplicity. It would work all the same with floats.

```
d = {1:['a', 'b', 'c'], 2:['d', 'e', 'f'], 3:['g', 'h', 'i']}

L = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

L_iter = iter(L)

new_d = {key: [val + next(L_iter) for val in sublist] for key, sublist in d.items()}

print(new_d)
# {1: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], 2: ['d4', 'e5', 'f6'], 3: ['g7', 'h8', 'i9']}
```

We create the new dict with a dict comprehension. Inside it, we create the new sublist with a list comprehension, iterating on `L` with the help of the iterator `L_iter`, which allows to get the next item of `L` each time.